# FB.api('/me') AJAX Post in Django

Tags: json, django, facebook-graph-api

My requirement is to grab the response from FBapi('/me',) and do a ajax post to a view to update the info to database. With the code below although I get a 200 on Ajax Post I am unable to retrieve the response using `request.POST['name']`,
`request.POST['birthday']` etc .

If I simply give a:-

```
def GetFBData(request):
    print(request)
```

I get: "WSGIRequest: POST '/login/facebook/" and an AJAX error message of Unexpected token at JSON position 1.

Below is my script :-

```
FB.api('/me', {
    fields: 'birthday,cover,devices,email,first_name,gender,id,last_name,link,location,name,name_format,timezone,verified,website,locale'},
    function(response) {
        response = JSON.stringify(response);
        $.ajax({
             url: '/login/facebook/',
             type: 'POST',
             data:{fb:response , window:window.ui},
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function (data) {
                 console.log(data);
             },
             error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                 alert(thrownError);
             }
        });
    });
```

How to correctly retrieve this response data on the view?

Comment: What is the output of `JSON.stringify(response)`? Please `console.log` that and edit the question with the output.

Comment: JSON.stringify response is as expected . I am getting the fields with the api data as expected.